# Replace spaces with an underscore in PHP while uploading file

Tags: php

I have a script that allows users to upload images. I'm working on something that grabs a random image from the collection of images, however the spaces seem to screw with the url, which means I need to figure out how to replace spaces with _s.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $target_file = str_replace(' ', '_', $target_file);
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

as you can see here, I tried adding `$target_file = str_replace(' ', '_', $target_file;)` to replace the string, however the image still uploads with spaces. How can I make this work?

Comment: you change the `$target_file` string after its actually used -- so no surprise it wont work

Answer (score 0):

In your code only the content of file name string is replaced.

Its not changing the actual file name.

You need to use `str_replace` before `move_uploaded_file`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    $target_file = str_replace(' ', '_', $target_file);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],  $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you replaced it after you upload, you should replace before you upload.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    $target_file = str_replace(' ', '_', $target_file);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```